# It's possible to invoke a new native function with COCOS2D javascript bindings

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I noticed that COCOs2d javascript hasn't some native functions needed for my game. It's possible to create a new native function and to invoke it from javascript ?

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the bindings:

www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_bind_C++_to_Javascript